# flutter inspector doesn't work for the app from my github repository

Tags: flutter

The flutter inspector doesn't work (not showing widgets tree) for my project (it's cloned from github).
To figure out what's wrong in my project, I generated new flutter applications, and the behavior is weird.

1. When I generate a new flutter application (flutter's default new flutter project) in a NEW directory, flutter inspector works ok.
2. If I make a new flutter application INSIDE my project directory (let's say myproject/temp), the inspector doesn't show the widgets tree.
3. If I delete my project directory (myproject), make a directory with the same name (myproject), and generate a new flutter application inside the directory (myproject/temp), then the inspector works ok.
4. If I make 'myproject' directory manually (mkdir myproject), copy all myproject files to myproject/ (cp myproject_backup/* myproject/), and generate a new flutter application inside myproject/temp, then the inspector doesn't work.
5. If I make 'myproject' directory manually (mkdir myproject), generate a new flutter application inside myproject/temp, copy all myproject files to myproject/ (cp myproject_backup/* myproject/), then the inspector doesn't work.

Can the other files in the same folder (myproject/*) affect the behavior of the flutter project (esp. inspector)?
What else can go wrong in this case?

Here's my setting:

```
Flutter: Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.5
Dart: version 2.8.2
Android SDK version 28.0.3
Android Studio (version 4.0)
Flutter plugin version 46.0.2
Dart plugin version 193.7361
```

Comment: Try stop running app and restart. If intellij or AS better invalidate cache and restart from files context menu.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I figured out the problem.

Comment: @user987654, Can you help! What was the problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app is inside bazel WORKSPACE, that was the problem.
If I delete WORKSPACE file, the inspector works fine.

Comment: Man, You saved my time.
Appreciate your answer. Keep helping even on the smallest tasks <3